# Custom pager button's id property - the button is disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

According to the [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons#definition), the `id` property of a custom pager button is:

> id : string (optional) - if set defines the id of the button (actually the id of TD element) for future manipulation

The problem is that when use/set (`id:'myCustomButton'`) this property, the button is disappeared.

How can I use it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you made some typing errors. Try with this code

```
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    caption: "My Button",
    id: "myCustomButton",
    onClickButton: function () {
        alert("Click!");
    }
});
```

and look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomNavButtonWithId.htm).

Comment: Using your code example, still refusing to work, still invisible. Might depends on a specific jqGrid version?

Comment: @YairNevet: Could you see that my demo works? Can you provide the code which you use? It's important to see exact calls of `navGrid` and `navButtonAdd`.

Comment: @YairNevet: The code of `navButtonAdd` is very simple (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L1981-2030)). You can just use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and set breakpoint on lines somewhere [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L1991-1995). You will quickly find the reason of the problem which you have.

Comment: I found the reason, it's all about a bug in an older jqGrid version (4.3.1). Thank you.